# How can I use Date Picker with django-filter?

Tags: django, datepicker, django-filter

I am trying to figure out how can I use datepicker with django-filter. I have tried a bunch of widgets but it's not working. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

I want to use datepicker for the row_date search filter.

`filters.py`

```
from home2.models import AvailstaticCopy
from django import forms

import django_filters

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class AvailFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model   = AvailstaticCopy
        widgets = {'row_date': DateInput(),}
        fields  = ['row_date', 'director','manager','analyst',]
```

This is my template

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form method="get">
  <div class="well">
    <h4 style="margin-top: 0">Filter</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        {{ filter.form.row_date.label_tag }}
        {% render_field filter.form.row_date class="form-control" %}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        {{ filter.form.director.label_tag }}
        {% render_field filter.form.director class="form-control" %}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        {{ filter.form.manager.label_tag }}
        {% render_field filter.form.manager class="form-control" %}
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        {{ filter.form.analyst.label_tag }}
        {% render_field filter.form.analyst class="form-control" %}
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not very clear what kind of datepicker you think of, but I assume you'd like to have something like this:
[jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

I hope you know how to use a third party JavaScript library. That should be out of the scope of this question.

Once you have set up your project to use jQuery UI you can change your `filters.py`:

```
class AvailFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    row_date = django_filters.DateFilter(
        widget=DateInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'datepicker'
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        # keep everything but the line widgets
```

Any widget you use accepts a keyword argument `attrs` which takes a dictionary, where you can specify all attributes of an HTML tag.

Now when you render `row_date` it should output something like this:

```
<input type="date" class="datepicker" ... />
```

Answer (score 13):

type="date" can help you without any widget (depends of browser):

```
class AvailFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    row_date = django_filters.DateFilter(widget=DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

also if you need date range filter, you can use DateFromToRangeFilter instead of DateFilter

Comment: it worked at first-time on firefox and edge (choomium based). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To provide another answer similar to cezar's answer, I did it this way below with my filter and template codes.

**filter.py**

```
import django_filters
from .models import Product
from django import forms

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    price = django_filters.NumberFilter()

    # using jquery
    djfdate_time = django_filters.DateFilter(
        lookup_expr='icontains',
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            attrs={
                'id': 'datepicker',
                'type': 'text'
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'djfdate_time','price']
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/search.css' %}">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1 ><a class="searchtitle" href="/">Django Filter Example</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        } );
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**base_extension.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load my_templatetags %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="get">
        <div>Name{{ filter.form.name }}</div>
        <div>Price{{ filter.form.price }}</div>
        <div>Date_Time{{ filter.form.djfdate_time }}</div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    {% for obj in dataqs.object_list %}  
        {{ obj.name }}
            <div>
                <li>${{ obj.price }}</li>
                <li> {{ obj.djfdate_time|date:'m-d H:i:s.u' }}</li>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```