# How can I use the jquery datepicker with django admin simplelist filter

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin

[How can I use Date Picker with django-filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054846/how-can-i-use-date-picker-with-django-filter)

does it with django-filters but I use SimpleListFilter.
I don't know how to incoorporate jquery that well yet.

I want to enable the user to select a date in the filterscreen to the right with a calendar widget, which is then checked whether this date is between a given time interval of start date and end date.

From what I have found is that the jquery datepicker is a simple solution but you need to be able to incoorporate this. I don't know where I put this code in.
I don't use any forms. Or I never used them myself. Not even called them for something. So I wasn't able to incorporate the widget neither. I wouldn't want to use form if that is possible.

I know that you can put your static files in the static folder, do

```
collectstatic
```

and then call the .js - File with

```
Class Media:

    js = ('myapp/static/js/myfile.js',)
```

One thing I couldn't find out was how to read out/write into the date from the DateField. I guessed mydatefield.default() as the shell gave me. But I neither know how to set a custom date with the shell.

Any help is appreciated. I know I'm quite new to this subject and anxious about asking wrongly.

**JQuery - Datepicker source code**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

**filters.py**

```
    class ContractDateFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    """

    Custom Filter to filter for Contracts which were active at a certain date.

    """
    title = _('qualifying date')
    parameter_name = 'is_active'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        customdate = DateField(default=date.today)
        return (
            (customdate.default(), '%s: %s' % (_('Custom Date'), _('Select via widget'))),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() is not None:
            return queryset.filter(begin__lte=self.value(),
                                   end__gte=self.value())
```